# Large file not flushed to disk immediately after calling close()?

Tags: python, windows, io, python-3.x, large-files

I'm creating large file with my python script (more than `1GB`, actually there's 8 of them). Right after I create them I have to create process that will use those files.

The script looks like:

```
# This is more complex function, but it basically does this:
def use_file():
    subprocess.call(['C:\\use_file', 'C:\\foo.txt']);


f = open( 'C:\\foo.txt', 'wb')
for i in 10000:
    f.write( one_MB_chunk)
f.flush()
os.fsync( f.fileno())
f.close()

time.sleep(5) # With this line added it just works fine

t = threading.Thread( target=use_file)
t.start()
```

But application `use_file` acts like `foo.txt` is empty. There are some weird things going on:

- if I execute `C:\use_file C:\foo.txt` in console (after script finished) I get correct results
- if I execute manually `use_file()` in another python console I get correct results
- `C:\foo.txt` is visible on disk right after `open()` was called, but remains size `0B` until the end of script
- if I add `time.sleep(5)` it just starts working as expected (or rather required)

I've already found:

- [`os.fsync()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync) but it doesn't seem to work (result from `use_file` is as if `C:\foo.txt` was empty)
- Using `buffering=(1<<20)` (when opening file) doesn't seem to work either

I'm more and more curious about this behaviour.

**Questions:**

- Does python *fork* `close()` operation into background? Where is this documented?
- How to work this around?
- Am I missing something?
- After adding `sleep`: is that a windows/python bug?

---

*Notes:* (for the case that there's something wrong with the other side) application `use_data` uses:

```
handle = CreateFile("foo.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
                               OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
size = GetFileSize(handle, NULL)
```

And then processes `size` bytes from `foo.txt`.

Comment: I suspect you are missing something, like full paths versus local files, perhaps.

Comment: Why are you naming a file written with `"wb"` (binary mode) as `foo.txt`? Confusing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm using absolute paths everywhere in my script (added `C:\\ ` to my question to make that explicit) + I'm dumping arguments of `subprocess.call()` (including `cwd`) into `stdout` and when they are used later it just works.

Comment: @unwind source files for those large files are at different encodings and we want to preserve encodings from original files (using bytes seems to work just fine for this purpose).

Comment: @unwind: In python 3, if you do not want / need to deal with encodings of text files, you open them in binary mode instead. Perfectly valid use of `wb` there.

Comment: are you sure there is enough space on the disk? There is a [bug in Python 3 that a file stays open after f.close() if implicit call to f.flush() fails](http://bugs.python.org/issue16597). Try to call f.flush() explicitly before f.close(). `os.fsync()` shouldn't be necessary unless there is a power-fail.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `Free bytes: 846 621 491 200`, this probably won't be an issue. But the server has quite an *IO load*.

Comment: To localize the issue call `use_file.use_file(filename)` 1. immediately after f.close() 2. in another thread 3. in another process (check_call()) 4. both in another thread and another process where use_file.py is: `def use_file(fn): assert os.path.getsize(fn) == sum(len(chunk) for chunk in iter(functools.partial(open(fn,'rb').read, 1 << 15), b'')) != 0`. To generate data: `for data in itertools.repeat(b"abcd" * (1<<18), 10000): f.write(data)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I've already found a way to fix those issues, but I most definitely don't like it.

Comment: @Vyktor those aren't _issues_ -- it's a way of working out exactly where the problem is. We don't at the moment know whether the file is being flushed, for example.

Comment: @Vyktor: I've created [a gist to help localize where the issue is](https://gist.github.com/902028ce8da51a8a7226). Just run `test_*.py` files. Each file runs ~5-10 minutes on a slow hdd. On my machine everything works.

Comment: @katrielalex I'm sorry but I don't get what you wanted to say

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm just leaving from work, but I'll test it first thing on Monday, but there are few things that I see are different, `1)` you're not starting new process from the thread (so windows may have some sort of tracing mechanism that will take a place or reuse file descriptor) `2)` "my" application `use_file` is written in low level WindowsAPI (so every mechanisms that python may use won't work on my side).

Comment: 1) test_4.py starts subprocess in a new thread 2) The purpose is to find *where* the issue is. The first step is to write a [complete minimal example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces it. "Complete" means self-contained if possible i.e., you can run it as is. "Minimal" means that if you can reproduces it without using threads/subprocesses/specific program then you should drop them.

Comment: The problem could be GetFileSize not returning up-to-date information; if you use ReadFile instead do you get the written data?  (Another thought: is it possible that Python is being over-clever and reordering instructions?)

Comment: I have this exact same behavior. But in my case, the external program is microsoft's hlsl compiler, fxc.exe, so I don't know how it accesses the file. Also, my files are quite small, a few kilobytes only. Did you ever find out what the issue was?

Comment: @EmilStyrke unfortunately no, I had to put sleep there...

Comment: @Vyktor Oh, too bad. That's the only solution I've found as well.

Comment: @Vyktor: [do you use redirection to run a subprocess in your actual code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761961/large-file-not-flushed-to-disk-immediately-after-calling-close/29249360#comment46909395_29249360)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`f.close()` calls `f.flush()`, which sends the data to the OS. That *doesn't* necessarily write the data to disk, because the OS buffers it. As you rightly worked out, if you want to force the OS to write it to disk, you need to `os.fsync()`.

Have you considered just piping the data directly into `use_file`?

---

EDIT: you say that `os.fsync()` 'doesn't work'. To clarify, if you do

```
f = open(...)
# write data to f
f.flush()
os.fsync(f.fileno())
f.close()

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and then look at the file on disk, does it have data?

Comment: Piping data is unfortunately not an option (it's proprietary application that we are using). I'm gonna check now whether those 3 commands are executed when and where they should. Please not that the `subprocess.call` is executed in new thread (create after calling close).

Comment: By default Windows uses write caching on hard disks, so normally almost no data is immediately written to disc. You can disable this in the Device Manager by double-clicking the hard disk under Disk Drives and then switching to the Policies tab and removing the check-mark next to the setting,

Comment: Adding `sleep(5)` (added to my question) fixed the issue. But I'm still looking for more *pythonic* and *correct* way to do this.

Comment: Although flush() doesn't necessarily write the data to the physical disk immediately, it should still be visible to other applications (from the cache) immediately.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: updated with information specific to Python 3.x

There is a super old bug report discussing a suspiciosly similar problem at https://bugs.python.org/issue4944.  I made a small test that shows the bug: https://gist.github.com/estyrke/c2f5d88156dcffadbf38

After getting a wonderful explanation from user eryksun at the bug link above, I now understand why this happens, and it is not a bug per se.  When a child process is created on Windows, by default it inherits all open file handles from the parent process.  So what you're seeing is probably actually a sharing violation because the file you're trying to read in the child process is open for writing through an inherited handle in *another* child process. A possible sequence of events that causes this (using the reproduction example at the Gist above):

```
Thread 1 opens file 1 for writing
  Thread 2 opens file 2 for writing
  Thread 2 closes file 2
  Thread 2 launches child 2
  -> Inherits the file handle from file 1, still open with write access
Thread 1 closes file 1
Thread 1 launches child 1
-> Now it can't open file 1, because the handle is still open in child 2
Child 2 exits
-> Last handle to file 1 closed
Child 1 exits
```

When I compile the simple C child program and run the script on my machine, it fails in at least one of the threads most of the time with Python 2.7.8.  With Python 3.2 and 3.3 the test script without redirection does not fail, because the default value of the `close_fds` argument to `subprocess.call` is now `True` when redirection is not used.  The other test script using redirection still fails in those versions.  In Python 3.4 both tests succeed, because of PEP 446 which makes all file handles non-inheritable by default.

### Conclusion

Spawning a child process from a thread in Python means the child inherits *all* open file handles, even from other threads than the one where the child is spawned. This is, at least for me, not particularly intuitive.

Possible solutions:

- Upgrade to Python 3.4, where file handles are non-inheritable by default.
- Pass `close_fds=True` to `subprocess.call` to disable inheriting altogether (this is the default in Python 3.x).  Note though that this prevents redirection of the child process' standard input/output/error.
- Make sure all files are closed before spawning new processes.
- Use `os.open` to open files with the `os.O_NOINHERIT` flag on Windows.

  - `tempfile.mkstemp` also uses this flag.
- Use the win32api instead.  Passing a NULL pointer for the `lpSecurityAttributes` parameter also prevents inheriting the descriptor:

  ```
  from contextlib import contextmanager
  import win32file

  @contextmanager
  def winfile(filename):
      try:
          h = win32file.CreateFile(filename, win32file.GENERIC_WRITE, 0, None, win32file.CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0)
          yield h
      finally:
          win32file.CloseHandle(h)

  with winfile(tempfilename) as infile:
      win32file.WriteFile(infile, data)
  ```

Comment: The OP didn't report a sharing violation.  I think perhaps this is a different issue?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Hmm, you're right. I think that is simply because the OP simply didn't check his error code (since the symptoms are exactly the same otherwise), but it may be as you say.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I rewrote the answer to make this more clear, and to be more clear in general.

Comment: What Python version do you use? Do any of [the tests](https://gist.github.com/zed/902028ce8da51a8a7226) fail on your Windows machine? [All handles are closed in OPs code (no redirection)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/#inheritance-of-file-descriptors-on-windows).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I have used 2.7.8, 2.7.9 (shows issue) and 3.4.1 (doesn't show issue, which is expected given the PEP you linked: default is to make handles non-inheritable since 3.4). None of your tests fail on my machine, but then again, as far as I can see they are unrelated to the explanation I've given in my answer. The OP explicitly says that his actual function is more complex, so I wouldn't trust that there's no redirection involved - Vyktor, can you confirm this?

Comment: @EmilStyrke: the question has python-3.x where I/O does not use C `FILE*` (different from Python 2). I've expected the tests to work but asked just in case. Even before Python 3.4, the handles are closed if there is no redirection, aren't they?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Indeed, I actually missed the python-3.x tag before. With 2.7 the failure occurs regardless of redirection or not, with 3.2 and 3.3 it works without redirection and fails with redirection (i.e. it tracks the close_fds default value). With 3.4 it works regardless of redirection because the handles are noninheritable by default. I guess we'll have to wait for the OP to clarify if redirection is used or not.