# python file io loop mystery (CPU goes disk sleep)

Tags: python, io

I'm looping histogram operation on HDF5 files of size ~800MB each (equal size).
The result of histogram is stored in text files each with ~5column x 30 lines.

```
t0 = time.time()
for f in filelist:
    d = h5py.File(f,'r')
    result = make_histogram(d['X'].value)
    ascii_write(result)
    print time.time()-t0
    d.close()
```

One pass through the loop normally seems to take ~6-7 seconds for each file.
However, at some point it takes significantly longer to pass one loop.
And this point in time seems to start rather randomly if I try running multiple times with different files starting first.

I noticed that in my system monitor, at this point, CPU is in "disk sleep".
How can I fix this?

It seems to be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761961/large-file-not-flushed-to-disk-immediately-after-calling-close), but I could not find a definitive answer.

Comment: Are you sure that `result` is always of a similar size? In order to get some insight, you may print debugging messages between each operation in order to see which one takes more time than usual. You can also use the Python profilers and get more information.

Comment: "D" (disk sleep) means that the process is waiting on a file descriptor. When your program starts to slow down, are you doing other things on the same HD? Maybe a buffering issue? I suppose that this behaviour has nothing to do with your script, but either with your kernel or your HD.

Comment: @EOL Yes, I'm sure ```result``` are of similar size (it's just bins and counts of a histogram (N_bins <~ 30), very small). Trying to use proflier... There must be a definitive condition when CPU goes to disk sleep state?